# Why did the minimum reputation for review first-posts got changed?

Tags: discussion, support

Till last week, I reviewed both first-post and late-answers. today, I can't. It says that *the users with 500 reputation can only review*.

When did this happen?

Comment: I saw this change too and the change must've been implemented this weekend as I was able to review friday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The why was apparently decided during a close look at all the privileges that happened last week on a network wide basis.

- [Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark)

There was some discussion that this review would be better placed at 1k or even higher, but on sites like ours with lower voting - the bump to 500 removed a larger fraction of total reviewers than on sites like stack overflow.